# where is the air filter on my Generac Guardian generator?

Tags: generator

Power went out today. The automatic backup generator (natural gas via utility line) started strong around 9am, but around 6 it started stuttering a lot. I turned it off for about 30 min, thinking maybe it needed a break, but trying to turn it back on later shows an underspin error.

I called Generac and they said this happens when the air filter gets snowy or wet (which it is right now) and that cleaning out the filter will usually work. They said there would be a big black box to the left of the control panel with the filter.

For the life of me, I can't figure out where the filter is. Below is a shot of the inside. Is it possible my air filter is missing or something?

[image]

Comment: What model number? Maintenance instructions are here: https://www.generac.com/service-support/product-support-lookup

Comment: Make a large box to feed air to the filter- air moves slowly in the large box so does not drag snow in. Design an overhang to shield intake.

Comment: @SolarMike thatll probably be part of the clean up from this. Do you have a recommendation now, while it is like 5 degrees and blizzard conditions? I cleared snow away from it and tried to block wind while it starts, but no luck

Comment: Did you clean / dry or replace the filter?

Comment: Search YouTube for *generac air filter*, you'll find clear guided instructions.

Comment: @jay613 that's the first thing I did. All the instructions I could find showed the air filter up above the engine next to the control panel. Mine is not like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching in the dark in a blizzard, I found the filter and managed to clean it and get the generated started.

For anyone that has a Generac Guardian 10kw and runs into this problem:

1. Open the top of the generator
2. Pull the front panel up (not forward) to open.
3. The air filter is inside a black box above the battery on the right side, under the control module. Open the latch, pull off the cover, and then you can get to the filter. I had a crap ton of snow logged in that area, so cleared that out too.

[image]

Comment: I added a screenshot form the manual. If it's the wrong one (you didn't specify model, so I inferred from  "10kW"), feel free to remove or delete.

Comment: @P2000 thanks for adding that. It's not quite what mine looks like, but it's close enough. The main difference is most generacs seem to have the air filter easily accessed from the main compartment, but in this one you need to remove the front panel and open a black box to find it. Clogged/wet filters were apparently a common issue with generates during the recent blizzard so non-mechanical people might need to get in there to clear it out during emergency usage.

Comment: ok good info, hopefully it's of use to the next person too. You can add your comment to the answer. comments get purged over time and are not indexed by search engines.